# Enclosing a list inside an ordered list using jQuery and printing it to the screen?

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = ['moe', 'joe', 'low', 'cow', 'dough'];
window.onload = function() {
    var newArr = document.querySelector(".rnd"); // rnd is div with a class called rnd.
    var elem = document.createElement('ol'); // Tried creating a new element ol to enclose the lists.
    console.log(elem); // For my purpose
    elem.appendChild(newArr); // Appending the ol inside the div which contains the lists.
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        newArr.innerHTML += '<li>' + arr[i] + '</li>';
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a list into an ordered list by making a new element which holds the `ol` tag and then appending the variable that holds all the `li` tags into the variable that holds the `ol` tag.

When I `console.log` this in my browser, the result seems to be what I want but the `ol` tags are around the `div` whereas I want the div tags to be around the `ol` tags.

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE8Cx.png)

Comment: it should be the other way around, considering the names, change the variables attribution: `var elem = document.querySelector(".rnd");` and `var newArr = document.createElement('ol');`

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ['moe', 'joe', 'low', 'cow', 'dough'];

window.onload = function()
{
var newArr = document.querySelector(".rnd");
var elem = document.createElement('ol');

console.log(elem);

newArr.appendChild(elem);

console.log(newArr);

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    elem.innerHTML += '<li>' + arr[i] + '</li>';
}
}
```

GOT THIS TO WORK! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should append the ol Tag to the div tag, e.g.

```
newArr.appendChild(elem);
```

appendChild appends the parameter **'into'** the calling element.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery and ECMA5 you can do it in one line with the following.

```
var arr = ['moe', 'joe', 'low', 'cow', 'dough'];
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('<ol>').append.call(arr.map(x => $('<li>' + x + '</li>'))).appendTo('.rnd');
})
```

This will:

1. Create a new `ol` tag.
2. Create a `li` tag for each element in the array
3. Run the 'call' prototype to append the array of `li` tags to the `ol`
4. Finally append itself, the `ol` element, to the `.rnd` div